# ReactJS application passing state to multiple pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a financial application in ReactJS.  The application will be making use of a custom web API to retrieve data from a a MS SQL database.  The initial landing page of the application requires the user to log in using his/her user ID and password.  Once the user has logged in successfully, the menu options are provided to the user (ie: review balance, transfer between accounts, pay bills, etc).

In my design, each menu function will be a separate component in its own src/screens member. My directory structure looks like this:

[image]

The app launches and executes the `src/screens/login.js` file and allows the user to log in. Once the user logs in, the state contains the user ID and password, a user ID and a 4 digit reference code.

If I were to create a `src/screens/account_balance.js` page, how would I get the state from `src/screens/index.js` into the state of `src/screens/account_balance.js`?  At the same time, when I create my `src/screens/transfer_balance.js` page, how would I get the state from `src/screens/index.js` into the state of `src/screens/transfer_balance.js`?

This is what my current login.js code looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/app.css';

//think of react components as functions
class login extends React.Component {    


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            passData: {
                passFamilyID: '',
                passPlanID: '',
                passMemberID: '',
                passPIN: ''
            },
            login: {
                errorMessage: '',
                errorCSS: 'visibility:hidden',
                buttonText: 'Log In'
            },  
            userID: {
                valid: true,
                value: '',
                label: 'User ID',
                length: 0,
                css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
            },        
            password: {
                valid: true,
                value: '',
                label: 'Password',
                length: 0,
                css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
            },
        }

    this.verifyLogin = this.verifyLogin.bind(this);
    }

    verifyLogin () {

        let currentComponent = this;
        var validData = true;
        var mqResponse = '';

        var localLogin = {
            errorMessage: '',
            errorCSS: 'visibility:hidden',
            buttonText: 'Log In'
            }
        var localUserID = {
            valid: true,
            value: '',
            label: 'User ID',
            length: 0,
            css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
            }
        var localPassword = {
            valid: true,
            value: '',
            label: 'Password',
            length: 0,
            css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
            }

        localUserID.value = document.getElementById("txtUserID").value;
        localPassword.value = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;

        if (localUserID.value.length < 3) {
            validData = false;
            localUserID.valid = false;
            localUserID.css = "input-group-text text-danger input-size-200";
            localLogin.errorMessage = "Invaid User ID length";
            localLogin.errorCSS = "text-danger";
        }  
        else {
            localUserID.css = 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200';
        }

        if (localPassword.value.length >= 5) {
            localPassword.css = 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200';
        } else {
            validData = false;
            localPassword.valid = false;
            localPassword.css = "input-group-text text-danger input-size-200";
            localLogin.errorCSS = "text-danger";
            if (localLogin.errorMessage == '') {
                localLogin.errorMessage = "Invalid Password length";
            } else {
                localLogin.errorMessage = "Invalid User ID and Password length";
            }
        }


        if (validData == false) {
            currentComponent.setState({ userID:localUserID, password:localPassword, login: localLogin });
        } else {
            localLogin.buttonText = "Please wait.....";
            currentComponent.setState({ userID:localUserID, password:localPassword, login: localLogin });

            var templocalUserID = document.getElementById("txtUserID").value + "                                                  ";
            var templocalPassword = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value + "                  ";

            var mqUserID= templocalUserID.substring(0,40);
            var mqPassword = templocalPassword.substring(0,10);
            var MQMessage = "6007sP0001????DEMI0000000000    INTERNET/093000050" + mqUserID + mqPassword;
            var mqResponse = "";
            var mqErrorCode = 0;

            MQMessage = encodeURI(MQMessage);
            let url = "http://localhost:12976/api/Homepage?mqRequest=" + MQMessage;
            const options = { method: 'GET' };

            fetch(url, options)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(myJson) {
                if (myJson == undefined) 
                {
                    console.log("fetch failed");
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    //inspect the data that the WebAPI returned
                    mqResponse = myJson[0].return_response;
                    mqErrorCode = myJson[0].return_code;
                    if (mqErrorCode > 0) {
                        localLogin.errorMessage = "We are having a problem connecting to our service. Please try again at a later time.";
                        localLogin.css = "input-group-text text-danger input-size-200";
                        localLogin.errorCSS = "text-danger";
                        currentComponent.setState({ userID:localUserID, password:localPassword, login:localLogin })
                    }   else {
                        var mqResponseCode = mqResponse.substr(0,3);
                        if (mqResponseCode > 0) {
                            localLogin.errorMessage = "Incorrect UserID/Password.";
                            localLogin.css = "input-group-text text-danger input-size-200";
                            localLogin.errorCSS = "text-danger";
                            currentComponent.setState({ userID:localUserID, password:localPassword, login:localLogin })
                        } else {
                            var localData = {
                                familyID: '    ',
                                planID: mqResponse.substr(27,4),
                                memberID: mqResponse.substr(13,10),
                                PIN: mqResponse.substr(23,4)
                            }
                            currentComponent.setState({ passData:localData })
                            location.href = "/account_balance";
                        }
                    }         
                }
            });
        }

    }

    render() {

            return (  
                <div className="App">      
                    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Access your 401(k)</a>
                    </nav>
                    <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center align-items-center align-content-center">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div>
                                    <form>
                                        <p className="h4 text-center py-4">Please Log In</p>
                                        <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                            <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                                <span className={this.state.userID.css}>{this.state.userID.label}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input id="txtUserID" type="text" className="form-control" />
                                        </div> 
                                        <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                            <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                                <span className={this.state.password.css}>{this.state.password.label}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input id="txtPassword" type="current-password" className="form-control" />
                                        </div> 
                                        <div className="text-center py-4 mt-3">
                                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => { 
                                            this.verifyLogin();
                                            }}>{this.state.login.buttonText}</button>
                                        </div>                                         
                                        <div className={this.state.login.errorCSS}>
                                            <p className="h4 text-center">{this.state.login.errorMessage}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
            <main details={this.state.passData} />
        }
}

export default login
```

When I execute the application, I enter a user ID and Password.  The data is retrieved and I pick up 4 pieces of data from the returned string.  I then push those 4 pieces of data into the state.  Then, I execute location.href='/account_balance'.

This redirects to the account_balance.js page.  This is the code in my account_balance.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/app.css';

//think of react components as functions
class account_balance extends React.Component {    


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        state = { 
            passData: {
                passFamilyID: this.props.details.passFamilyID,
                passPlanID: this.props.details.passPlanID,
                passMemberID: this.props.details.passMemberID,
                passPIN: this.props.details.passPIN
            }
        }
    }

componentWillUpdate() {

    console.log("passedData: ", state.passedData);
    MQMessage  = "6000" + "sP0000" + "????" + state.passData.passPlanID + state.passData.passMemberID + state.passData.FamilyID + "INTERNET/";
    mqResponse = "";
    mqErrorCode = 0;

    MQMessage = encodeURI(MQMessage);
    url = "http://localhost:12976/api/Homepage?mqRequest=" + MQMessage;

    fetch(url, options)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
        if (myJson == undefined) 
        {
            console.log("fetch failed");
        } 
        else 
        { 
            //inspect the data that the WebAPI returned
            mqResponse = myJson[0].return_response;
            mqErrorCode = myJson[0].return_code;  
            console.log("mqErrorCode: ", mqErrorCode);
            console.log("mqResponse: ", mqResponse);      
        }
    });
}

    render() {

        return (  
            <div className="App">  
                <div>
                    <label>output from account_balance.js</label> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>{this.state.passData.passFamilyID}</label> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>{this.state.passData.passPlanID}</label> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>{this.state.passData.passMemberID}</label> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>{this.state.passData.passPIN}</label> 
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default account_balance
```

When the account_balance.js page loads, I see this in the console.log():

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'passFamilyID' of undefined
>       at new main (main.js:12)

When i click on the link to the line generating the error, this is what I see:

[image]

Comment: 1 - Show us what you've tried and where you're getting stuck/what errors you're encountering.  As others will tell you, this isn't a code writing service.
2 - Do NOT store a full social security number client side.  Ever.

Comment: @jonathan you can use props to share the state data from one component to another, or you can use redux as global state, but for beginners redux may be little confusing.

Comment: @MohamedSameer I have modified my post to include the code that I am running along with the errors that I am now receiving after trying to implement the solution suggested

Comment: hey, <main details={this.state.passData} change this into <account_balance detaisl={this.state.passData}

Comment: Good approach for component name is to start with Capital letter.

Comment: instead of <main> you need to pass your component name, then only you able to access into props.

Comment: I changed <main details={this.state.passData} to <Account_balance details={this.state.passData}.  I also changed "class account_balance extends React.Component" to "class Account_balance extends React.Component" and I changed "export default account_balance" to "export default Account_balance".  I still get the same error.  Your example show how to pass a single field, state.name.  I am trying to send an object.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: @JonathanSmall try this  <Account_balance details={...this.state.passData} by using spread operator ...

Comment: It likes that even less.  I get this when I refresh the browser on the login.js page: Module build failed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180015/discussion-between-mohamed-sameer-and-jonathan-small).

Answer (score 0):

you can use props to share the state data from one component to another, or you can use redux as global state.

For example your index.js state looks like:

```
state = {
   name: 'sameer',
}

render() {
  return (
    <Accountbal details={this.state.name} />
  )
}
```

Now your Account bal component code looks like account_bal.js

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  state = {
       name: this.props.details, // here you can access the name from index.js
    }

} 

render() {
  return (
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the suggestion by Mohamed Sameer and incorporated the code.  After trial and error, and additional research on the web, I found out a  command.  I removed my location.href which I was using to redirect to the account_balance.js and added a state variable Boolean to let me know if I want to redirect on the render.

In the render, I placed this code:

```
        if (this.state.passData.redirect === true) {           
        return ( 
            <Redirect to={{
                pathname: "/account_balance",
                state: {
                    familyID: this.state.passData.passFamilyID,
                    planID: this.state.passData.passPlanID,
                    memberID: this.state.passData.memberID,
                    PIN: this.state.passData.PIN
                }
            }}/>
        )
      }
```

This passes the state variables from the current page to the account_balance page.

In the account_balance.js, I put in this line of code:

> console.log("props: ", this.props.location.state);

Just to test the functionality.  When the account_balance,js loads, I looked at the console.log() and I saw the values I passed.